# Send port in Biztalk while configuring agreement

Tags: biztalk, edi

What does Send Port signify in Party Agreement Configuration.

I have configure Agreement many time.But i never understood why is send port is given.

please let me know what does send port signify in party Agreement configuraion and what is the use of send port configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you receive EDI (X12, EDIFact etc.) we can identify the party by using the header information.

When you send "EDI XML" to a send port, the send port has no way of identifying the party in the body XML and therefore we need to "tell it" which party/agreement it is part of, so that the EDISend pipline knows what headers etc. to place on the outgoing EDI.